# unexpected WSL error when i launch docker desktop

Tags: windows, docker

I just installed Docker Desktop on a Windows Server 2022. When I launch the application I get this error:

[image]

In powerShell:

```
$ C:\Users\user  bcdedit /enum | findstr -i hypervisorlaunchtype
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto

$ C:\Users\user> Systeminfo.exe
...
Version BIOS:                            Microsoft Corporation Hyper-V UEFI
...
System requirements for Hyper-V:         A hypervisor has been detected

$ C:\Users\user> wsl -l -v
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no distributions installed.
Use 'wsl.exe --list --online' to list available distributions
and 'wsl.exe --install <Distro>' to install.
Distributions can also be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
Error code: Wsl/WSL_E_DEFAULT_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND

$ C:\Users\user> wsl --install
Download: Ubuntu
Installation: Ubuntu
Ubuntu has been installed.
Launching Ubuntu...
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
```

*hypervisorlaunchtype auto* mean virtualization is enabled in the BIOS isn't it?

Comment: to set your default distro, in a terminal as admin run `wsl -d distro-name` (the one you installed). Names can be found with command `wsl --list --online`. After running `wsl -d`, the command `wsl -l -v` should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it...

You have to turn on the WSL 2 feature
Turn on the WSL 2 feature on Windows. For detailed instructions, [refer to the Microsoft documentation.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)

Upon installing Ubuntu distributions if you getting some virtualization BIOS error then you have to enable it from BIOS setting.

If you have any questions pls ask.